# How do I open a file that has another Blender file Appended to it?

Tags: append

I have a landscape with a lighthouse appended into it.  I saved the file and exited.  Now when I try to open it the search window goes to the list of items to be appended.  When I choose the lighthouse the file fails to open.  I suppose it may be corrupted.  If so, is there a backup that I could open instead?

Since I did decide that the file was corrupted, I changed the file extension of the backup file from ".blend1" to ".blend".  I did append the file name as well.  The backup was the same as the corrupted file, minus the last thing I did before saving and leaving the file.

This sure was better than having to start from scratch.

Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I am not sure how many backup versions Blender saves by default, but if you take a look into the directory of the corrupted .blend file there should be files with the same name but a file extensions like .blend1, .blend2... These are backup files. Just change the extension to .blend and you should be able to load them in Blender.

Comment: @Randy Van Nostrand appending does not effect the original nor the appended to file could you clarify the question more

Comment: @maddin45 No need to change the extension - just associate it with Blender.